# Set margins between items on BrowseFragment

Tags: android, android-tv

Developing an application for Android TV, I faced a problem for the usage of BrowseFragment provided by Leanback support library.
Can we change the margin between items of RowsFragment?

Comment: Is padding the elements a solution?

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, I could found a solution after all.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

I found the answer by myself. The key was HorizontalGridView which stores the each rows item list. We can get the reference of this HorizontalGridView by R.id.row_content. Finally, setItemMargin method was the solution for this.
Below is a sample code, and I could get top image.

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
    HorizontalGridView horizontalGridView = (HorizontalGridView) parent.findViewById(R.id.row_content);
    horizontalGridView.setItemMargin(400); // You can set item margin here.

    ...

    };
```

Comment: how can i set vertical margin for the list rows. could u pls help me with this.

Comment: Try like `((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) horizontalGridView.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100);`
You can change the margin of horizontalGridView itself.

Comment: ok i will try. and also can u tell me how can i set up white border to card displayed in rows ?

Comment: how to set margin for 1st item on left side only?

Comment: will you not mark your own answer as the correct? It could help lot of others searching

Answer (score 12):

You can override some styles to achieve this, for example:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Leanback" parent="Theme.Leanback">
  ..
  <item name="rowHorizontalGridStyle">@style/TvHorizontalGridView</item>
  ..
</style>

<style name="TvHorizontalGridView" parent="Widget.Leanback.Row.HorizontalGridView">
    <item name="horizontalMargin">@dimen/margin_medium</item>
    <item name="verticalMargin">@dimen/margin_medium</item>
</style>
```

where `@dimen/margin_medium` is the size of the margin that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally override the style details as @Billy answered. It can unfortunately take a while to figure out whats what. If what you are looking for is not styleable you can apparently override the built-in leanback resources (not sure if reliable/safe though). eg:

```
<dimen name="lb_browse_rows_margin_top">167dp</dimen>
<dimen name="lb_browse_item_vertical_spacing">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="lb_browse_expanded_row_no_hovercard_bottom_padding">28dp</dimen>
```

Comment: I suggest to create different styles for these instead of overriding the default resources as they are reused a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case when there was a need to implement an endless scroll in ListRow. Also, I needed to add extra space after each last item. So I solved this issue by adding custom presenter to adapter's presenterSelector:

```
class EmptySpacePresenter : Presenter() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
    val emptySpaceView = FrameLayout(parent.context).apply {
        val width = context.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.gallery_carousel_horizontal_gap).toInt()
        layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
        isClickable = false
        isFocusable = false
        isFocusableInTouchMode = false
    }

    return ViewHolder(emptySpaceView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder?, item: Any?) = Unit

override fun onUnbindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder?) = Unit
```

}

```
class MyObjectAdapter() : ArrayObjectAdapter() {

    init {
        presenterSelector = ClassPresenterSelector()
            .addClassPresenter(ListItem::class.java, ListItemPresenter())
            .addClassPresenter(EmptySpace::class.java, EmptySpacePresenter())
    }
}
```

Comment: EmptySpace.class contains what? I have not found anything in leanback libarary.

Answer (score 0):

In **Presenter** class **onCreateViewHolder** method,we can set parameters using **setItemSpacing**,**setPadding** e.t.c

```
class TVPresenter() : Presenter() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
     parent.findViewById<HorizontalGridView>(R.id.row_content).run {
                setItemSpacing(10)
                setPadding(40,10,40,10)
            }
     val cardViewLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false)
     return ViewHolder(cardViewLayout)
}
```